# JMeter: how to execute a different part of a testplan each threadloop

Tags: jmeter, throughput

I'm having the following scenario:

Thread group

1: http request 1

2: http request 2

3: http request 3

4: http request 4

I'm running this threadgroup with a fixed number of threads in a loop for a specified duration. 
Now I'm trying to figure out a way to only execute a certain request each thread loop for a certain percentage.

Let's say I want to have something like 50%: request 1 & 2 and 50%: request 3 & 4.
Also within those 50%'s that I would like to have another dimension like request 1: 75% request :2 25% and request 3: 95% request 4: 5%

i'm not looking to divide the number of threads here (which a troughput controller would do) but to take a specific path each time the threadgroup loops arround.

Is there any controller that can do this out of the box? Or am I better of using an IF controller based on a variable that I up each time (perhaps even the threadloop number which I mod) and then run the correct "scenario" based on that loop number?

Any tips, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

If you

1. Provide [`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) as the "Switch Value"

   [image]
2. Add i.e. [Simple Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) and name it like `0`, `1`, etc. and put the Samplers you want to execute under the Simple Controllers

This way 1st Thread Group iteration will trigger the children of the Simple Controller with the name `0`, 2nd Thread Group iteration will kick off the children of the Simple Controller with the name `1`, etc.

[image]

Sub-distribution can be established either the same way of using i.e. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller). See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability/) to learn more about different approaches to distributing JMeter's requests.